# TYPO3 create a foreach loop

Tags: foreach, typo3, fluid, typo3-6.2.x

I have the following situation. I have one content element in my backend layout where I add my records and I can successfully display them on the front end. However, I would like to have each new record inside my content element to get wrapped by a `<li></li>`, instead of having all in one.

My understanding is it would be best to use a foreach loop, but I'm not sure where to start. I know how to create the loop, but don't know how to get my content element inside it.

This is how I call the content:

```
styles.content.content2 < styles.content.get
styles.content.content2.select.where = colPos=1

lib.content2 < styles.content.content2
```

And in the HTML:

```
<li>
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.content2"></f:cObject>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the VHS extension
https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/1.8.0/Content/RenderViewHelper.html

Comment: Could you elaborate a little?